# How to add multiple resource in additionalloginparams in Azure Resource Explorer

Tags: python, angular, azure-active-directory, nestjs, azure-appservice

I have a frontend and 2 backend app service registered in Azure AD.

1. Backend-1 (main server) (nestjs)
2. Backend-2 (called to do one task) (python)

How it works:

- Frontend only calls backend-1
- backend-1 will call backend-2 to do a specific task.

I've followed instructions here [Tutorial: Authenticate and authorize users end-to-end in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux#configure-auth) to access my backend, unfortunately with this tutorial I can only access one since I can only put 1 "resource" in "additionalloginparams".

```
"additionalLoginParams": [
      "response_type=code id_token",
      "resource=<app-id of backend 1>",
      "(String)"
]
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
"additionalLoginParams": [
      "response_type=code id_token",
      "resource=<app-id of backend 1>",
      "resource=<app-id of backend 2>"
      "(String)"
    ],
```

what I'm trying right now is, I'm using the `access_token` which I got from `<frontend-appname>/.auth/me` (Frontend) to make api calls to **Backend-1** which is working since I already configure it in azure AD and Resource explorer "additionalLoginParams" (based from the tutorial). I'm also passing that `access_token` to **Backend-1**. This time the **Backend-1** will call **Backend-2** using the `access_token` as Authorization Header, it doesn't work since **Frontend**'s `access_token` dont have access to **Backend-2**.

Is there any other option you can suggest to access or make api calls to my 2 backend just using the `access_token` of **Frontend** as Authorization Bearer?

or maybe **Backend-1** should have its own `access_token` to access **Backend-2**, what approach should I do to achieve that?

Comment: Did you have a look of OBO flow? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Comment: @AllenWu Haven't tried that one yet, but it looks like what I need. I'll try that one. Many Thanks!.

Comment: Np, keep posted if there is any update.

Answer (score 0):

OBO flow should be suitable for your scenario.

It serves the use case where an application invokes a service/web API, which in turn needs to call another service/web API.

[image]

See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).